# Button in iOS app behaving unexpectedly on VM

Tags: ios, swift, virtualbox, vmware

I don't own a MacBook, so I installed macOS Mojave on VirtualBox.

I tried to do a simple thing, following the Stanford's Swift tutorial, which is to add a card (button) and flip it when clicking it.

I added the button to the main view, created the connection to the `ViewModel`, and typed the following code:

```
@IBAction func touchCard(_ sender: UIButton) {
    flipCard(withEmoji: "", on: sender)
}    

func flipCard(withEmoji emoji: String, on button: UIButton){
    if button.currentTitle == emoji {
        button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor =  colorLiteral(red: 0.9372549057, green: 0.3490196168, blue: 0.1921568662, alpha: 1)
    }
    else {
        button.setTitle(emoji, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor =  colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Tested this code on a genuine Mac PC and it works as expected. The button turns orange with no label on it upon click, and when clicking again, it turns white, and the ghost icon is placed on it.

However, when running it on the virtual machine, the button doesn't turn orange, and the ghost icon turns from regular to faded when I click on it.

What am I missing here? Is that somehow related to the VM?

Comment: have you actually connected the IBOutlets and IBActions in the VM one?

Comment: Yes I have, I can see that it is connected correctly when I hover over the dot to the left of the `IBAction`. Also, I see a change when I click, but the expected change...